# hadoop namenode -format DEPRECATED:

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

```
kavi@ubuntu:~/hadoop-2.2.0/bin$ ./hadoop namenode -format
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

/home/kavi/hadoop-2.2.0/bin/hdfs: line 201: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/java: No such file or directory
kavi@ubuntu:~/hadoop-2.2.0/
```

this is the error displayed...what i need to do...
please guide me to complete this process

Comment: You need to provide more context. What is going on here?

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Hadoop and Java?

Answer (score 1):

Use the undeprecated command that replaced hadoop namenode: hdfs namenode. For more information, see the [HDFS Commands Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#namenode).